# Yocto: m4-native-1.4.17-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed when running bitbake on a basic Raspberry Pi 3 image

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am new to Embedded Linux and am trying to build a Yocto image by following a tutorial. I install all of the necessary packages and utilities, download the source code, define a network configuration and build environment, and try to bitbake the image, but I run into this error:

```
ERROR: m4-native-1.4.17-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
```

This is the full output text after running:

```
bitbake rpi-basic-image
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/775wB.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmWVG.png)

I have cleaned and rebuilt the image several times and tried solutions online that look similar, but nothing seems to work. If you need more information, let me know, and I'll do my best to provide it.

Comment: `tried solutions online that look similar` - what have you tried exactly? The first hit on Google for `m4 SIGSTKSZ` query seems to be the exact same problem, along with a solution.